# Is an 'invoke'-style callback possible in PHP5?

Tags: php, callback, invoke

PHP functions such as 'array_map' take a callback, which can be a simple function or a class or object method:

```
$array2 = array_map('myFunc', $array);
```

or

```
$array2 = array_map(array($object, 'myMethod'), $array);
```

But is there a syntax to pass a method which is bound within the iteration to the current object (like 'invoke' in Prototype.js)? So that the following could be used:

```
$array2 = array_map('myMethod', $array);
```

with the effect of

```
foreach($array as $obj) $array2[] = $obj->myMethod();
```

Obviously I can use this form, or I can write a wrapper function to make the call, and even do that inline. But since 'myMethod' is already a method it seems to be going round the houses to have to do one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function obj_array_map($method, $arr_of_objects) {
    $out = array();
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    foreach ($arr_of_objects as $key => $obj) {
        $out[$key] = call_user_func_array(Array($obj, $method), $args);
    }
    return $out;
}

// this code
$a = Array($obj1, $obj2);
obj_array_map('method', $a, 1, 2, 3);

// results in the calls:
$obj1->method(1, 2, 3);
$obj2->method(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Not currently. When php 5.3 comes out, you could use the following syntax:

```
$array2 = array_map(function($obj) { return $obj->myMethod(); }, $array);
```

Comment: Which is longer and less obvious than my foreach method. Thanks.

Comment: It's ugly alright, but at least it doesn't use temp variables. If you come from a function-oriented language, such as Ruby or lisp, it appears more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. There is no special syntax to make this any easier.

I can think of a fancier way of doing this in PHP 5.3, seeing as there's always more than one way to do things in PHP, but I'd say it wouldn't necessarily be *better* than your *foreach* example:

```
$x = array_reduce(
    $array_of_objects, 
    function($val, $obj) { $val = array_merge($val, $obj->myMethod()); return $val; },
    array() 
);
```

Just go with your foreach :)

Comment: The third parameter of array_reduce() must be an integer, so this solution wouldn't work. $ReasonsToHatePhp++;

Comment: Actually, that appears to be a documentation error. The prototype in ext/standard/array.c:4015 defines it as 'mixed'.

Comment: Try running the code. You will notice, that you will receive 0 in the first recursion - and not an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// $obj->$method(); works, where $method is a string containing the name of the
// real method
function array_map_obj($method, $array) {
    $out = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $obj)
        $out[$key] = $obj->$method();

    return $out;    
}

// seems to work ...

class Foo {
    private $y = 0;
    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->y = $x;
    }
    public function bar() {
        return $this->y*2;
    }
}

$objs = array();
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++)
    $objs[] = new Foo($i);

$res = array_map_obj('bar', $objs);

var_dump($res);

?>
```

voila!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a silly answer, but you could subclass ArrayObject and use that instead of a normal array:

```
<?php

class ArrayTest extends ArrayObject {
    public function invokeMethod() {
        $result = array();
        $args = func_get_args();
        $method = array_shift($args);
        foreach ($this as $obj) {
            $result[] = call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method), $args);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

//example class to use
class a { 
    private $a;
    public function __construct($a) { 
        $this->a = $a; 
    }

    public function multiply($n) {
        return $this->a * $n;
    }
 }

//use ArrayTest instance instead of array
$array = new ArrayTest();
$array[] = new a(1);
$array[] = new a(2);
$array[] = new a(3);

print_r($array->invokeMethod('multiply', 2));
```

Outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `create_function()` to ... well ... create a temporary function for array_map while waiting for PHP 5.3

```
$func = create_function('$o', '$o->myMethod();');
array_map($func, $objects);
```

Comment: I can't really see any point in using create_function and not use it inline. If you are going to assign it to the variable $func, you might as well create a named function.

Comment: Use it inline, then. I don't like my source code growing too long (horizontally). Besides, storing it in a variable makes it clear to anyone looking at the source code that this function is used nowhere else.